# SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number JavaScript error in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7, jquery-1.4

I am getting this error at the line

```
 $('#' + tsid).find('tr:not(:first)').each(function () {
```

I checked [here](http://mikemclin.net/fixing-error-script1028-expected-identifier-string-or-number/), there are no extra commas, or reserved keys that I have used

here's the complete code block

```
 if ($("#" + tsid).find("tr").length == 0) {
                if (tsid == "Medicaltable") {
                    $("#" + tsid).prepend("<tr class='medicalheader' style='background-color:#D9EEF3;font-weight:bold'><td colspan='11'>Medical Information</td></tr>");
                 //   $("#Medicaltable tr:eq(1)").css("background-color", "rgb(217,238,243)");
                }

                if (tsid == "Vehicletable") {
                   $("#" + tsid).prepend("<tr style='background-color:#9BBB58;font-weight:bold'><td colspan='11'>VEHICLE ACCIDENT DETAILS</td></tr>");
                 //   $("#Vehicletable tr:eq(1)").css("background-color", "rgb(217,228,188)");
                }

                if (tsid == "Thefttable") {
                    $("#" + tsid).prepend("<tr style='background-color:rgb(242,221,220);font-weight:bold'><td colspan='11'>MEDICAL INFORMATION</td></tr>");
                   // $("#Thefttable tr:eq(1)").css("background-color", "rgb(242,221,220)");
                }
            }

              $('#' + tsid).find('tr:not(:first)').each(function () {
                if ($(this).find("td:eq(2)").find(":checkbox").is(":checked")) {
                    $(this).find("td:eq(3)").attr("editable", "false");

               } else {
                    $(this).find("td:eq(3)").attr("editable", "false");
                    $(this).find("td:eq(4)").attr("editable", "true");

                }
            });

        }
```

Comment: @JensonMJohn He has tagged IE7 :)

Comment: which jquery version?

Comment: @sajd The extra curly closing brace is really needed?

Comment: If i remember it, ':not()' was quite buggy in the past, so maybe just try instead: `.find('tr').not(':first')` or `.find('tr').not(':eq(0)')` just in case  EDIT: now i think it was `:has()` which was buggy, but anyway...

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention its jQuery 1.4.1

Comment: @A.Wolff it doesn't work tried both options